# No chat for mobile-app?

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-app

I love stack exchange and its mobile app however I feel it is missing the ability to use the chat in the mobile app.
Everytime I want to chat I have to go to my mobile browser and sign in again and even still the chat is a little buggy.

Why can't you chat in the mobile app? Is it not possible or is there a reason it is not included?

Comment: Also thought I would add that flagging a question on mobile app now causes app to crash...

Comment: If you'd like to report a bug, report a bug by asking a question. Mentioning it in comments isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Why not? Resources. SE is not that big to allow themselves to spend unlimited resources on something with zero profit.